# How do I run pycdc?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to decompile a .pyc into a .py to avoid rewriting some code, but I don't understand the instructions given in the description on [the page for pycdc on GitHub](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc).

I downloaded it, but how do I run the decompiler? It says `./bin/pycdc [PATH TO PYC FILE]` but I'm not sure what this means. I typed that in the command prompt and it doesn't recognize it. What do I need to do?

Comment: Also, I'm using windows.

Comment: On windows, say you are on the root directory i.e inside pycde, do
`bin\pycde yourfile` where yourfile is the file you want to decompile. If your file is in C:\tmp\yourfile.pyc, do `bin\pycde C:\tmp\yourfile.pyc`

Comment: Also make sure you first build it using Visual Studio.

Comment: @Rbk I tried doing as you said, but the cmd prompt tells me that bin\pycde is not recognized. I downloaded the folder and I typed cd to go into the pycde-master folder then the rest as you indicated. What is wrong now? Heh, I almost need a step-by-step to understand this.

Comment: does your bin folder contain the pycde file? If not you need to compile it using Visual Studio. There is a .sln file in the repo. Open that in VS and compile.

Comment: N/m found the .sln file.

Comment: In the root directory, i.e in pycde-master folder, there is pycdc.vcproj. Open that and then Build.

Comment: @RBK +1 to convert this to an answer…

Comment: ok. Will convert to an answer :)

Comment: One more problem - I opened that file in visual studio pressed, and pressed f5, but I'm getting an error that says it's unable to start the program and there is no file in bin. What now? Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: Try Build->Build Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `./` notation only applies to unix shell commands. This does not apply to Windows. It means you have to run `pydc [PATH TO PYC FILE]`, where `[PATH to PYC FILE]`, is the directory to the pyc file. For example:

If your pyc file is named `example.py` and is located in `C:\Users\Bobby\example.py` then you would type:

```
python pycdc C:\Users\Bobby\example.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you first build it using Visual Studio. 
There is a pycdc.vcproj in the repo. Double-click that to open Visual Studio. Then build it. This would put the pycde executable in the \bin folder.

Then from the root directory i.e from pycde-master folder, do

`bin\pycde yourfile`

where yourfile is the file you want to decompile. If your file is in `C:\tmp\yourfile.pyc`, do

```
bin\pycde C:\tmp\yourfile.pyc
```